# How to retrieve PIM contact's photo as Bitmap using RIM5.0?

Tags: blackberry, bitmap, contacts, pim, rim-5.0

I want to retrieve contacts' images and display them in `BitmapField`s.
So I'm collecting Bitmap objects from contacts, using this code:

```
Vector bitmaps = new Vector();
BlackBerryContactList contactList = (BlackBerryContactList)BlackBerryPIM.getInstance().openPIMList(BlackBerryPIM.CONTACT_LIST, BlackBerryPIM.READ_WRITE);
Enumeration contactListItems = contactList.items();
int counter = 0;
while (contactListItems.hasMoreElements()) {
    BlackBerryContact contact = (BlackBerryContact)contactListItems.nextElement();
    byte[] imageBytes = contact.getBinary(BlackBerryContact.PHOTO, counter);
    EncodedImage encodedImage = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
    Bitmap bitmap = encodedImage.getBitmap();
    bitmaps.addElement(bitmap);
    counter++;
}
```

Unfortunately the code throws a `java.lang.IllegalArumentException` at this method:

```
EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
```

How shoud I convert `byte[]` image to `BitmapField` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution for those who are interested, images retrieved from PIM are Base64 encoded, it should be decoded first. Here's the correct code:

```
Vector bitmaps = new Vector();
BlackBerryContactList contactList = (BlackBerryContactList)BlackBerryPIM.getInstance().openPIMList(BlackBerryPIM.CONTACT_LIST, BlackBerryPIM.READ_WRITE);
Enumeration contactListItems = contactList.items();
while (contactListItems.hasMoreElements()) {
    BlackBerryContact contact = (BlackBerryContact)contactListItems.nextElement();
    byte[] imageBytesBase64 = contact.getBinary(BlackBerryContact.PHOTO, 0);
    byte[] imageBytes = Base64InputStream.decode(imageBytesBase64, 0, imageBytesBase64.length);
    EncodedImage encodedImage = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
    Bitmap bitmap = encodedImage.getBitmap();
    bitmaps.addElement(bitmap);
}
```